# Put prefix on all elements of xml document

Tags: c#, prefix

I'm using C# and i need to create a XML document. Ok, i did, but, in each element i need to put a tc prefix.

The only way that i know, is using `xmlDoc.CreateElement("tc", "node1", "file.xsd")`, but it is very massive because i have lots of tags and my program its already writted.

Is this the only way?

Comment: Maybe you could show us some of the code you used, so we don't have to make a guess?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

[XmlReader - I need to edit an element and produce a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502450/xmlreader-i-need-to-edit-an-element-and-produce-a-new-one/2296248#2296248)

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky enough to be using C# 3.5, take a look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Here's a document on [How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (C#) (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) from MSDN for the LINQ to XML API.

And if you've never seen LINQ to XML before, take a look at this [5 minute overview](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)