# Removing xml nodes without using XmlDocument or XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to remove the xml nodes from the XML file without using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`.
I got many examples from net which all discuss about either `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`(Linq2XML).
i can not use either of the options(`XmlDocument` or Linq2XML `Xdocument`) because of the following 2 reasons:

1.they load the whole Xml file into memory and perform the opertaions (like remove node,add node etc.,) in my case Xml files are very huge.
2.both `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` crash if there is an invalid character in xml file.

Please suggest me some good alternative of removing the nodes without using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`.

Comment: You should look at Regular Expressions ([Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx),  [Regular Expression Language Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)) they are very good at processing large strings.

Comment: for that i need to first load the whole document into memory which is very expensive again :(

Comment: `XmlReader` + `XmlWriter` maybe : [XmlReader - I need to edit an element and produce a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502450/xmlreader-i-need-to-edit-an-element-and-produce-a-new-one)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what kind of edit you need to do? Is it possible to "stream" the file? I've used html agility pack with great success before when encountering bad formatting and chars, (though it still loads into memory) http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: i need to remove specific node from the xml file.

Comment: Does the node have sub-nodes? Should they be removed as well?

Comment: @flindeberg: yes it has subnodes and i have to remove complete node

Comment: why not use a stream to read in the lines checking for the node you wish to remove.  Once you find the node you just need to then find the closing element tag and you should then have the start and end position of what needs to be removed.